# Etymology of the term "weight vector"

Tags: soft-question, terminology, representation-theory

I am writing a work on the representation theory of $SU(3)$ in [basque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basque_language) and I would like to know the etymology of the term $\textbf{weight vector}$ in order to properly translate it.

Comment: I have asked a variant of this question here: http://mathoverflow.net/q/154933/27465 and already received helpful responses.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg thank you very much!